# Pipeline in linux command is not working.

Tags: linux, pipeline

I just want to create a file filled with half of increasing numbers followed by half of decreasing numbers using pipeline. So I could automate the process to generate thousand of files. Below is my code and generated files output.

**shuf -i 1-10 -n 6 | sort -n |shuf -i 11-20 -n 6|sort -r  > a.txt**

20
18
17
13
12
11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate them into two commands:

```
shuf -i 1-10 -n 6 | sort -n > a.txt && shuf -i 11-20 -n 6 | sort -r >> a.txt
```

`>>` allows you to append to file

`&&` to execute a second command in one line